# SSRS: Count rows based on specific value

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to get a small tablix to display counts based on the existence of 1 of 2 available values. Now, this is simple enough to get the data, as I've done here:

`=count(IIF(Fields!status.Value = "live_person", 1, nothing))`

`=count(IIF(Fields!status.Value = "voicemail/no answer", 1, nothing))`

[image]

But the problem I can't seem to get around is the existence of the extraneous row that contains a zero.
[image]

So what I want to display is this:

[image]

Is there a way to do this in one tablix (with an expression) without creating another dataset?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Doesn't seem like an SQL Server question, just SSRS?

Comment: what is the tablix grouped on?

Comment: Harry - It's grouped on the status column

Comment: That was the right question to ask Harry. It occurred to me after reading it that if I remove the group, it won't group the zero. Problem solved. Thank you!